# Category page when using static front page

Tags: posts, categories

I'm using a "static" front page with the posts on a page called News. Is it possible to make the categories use that as the base? Like this:

/news/[category_name]/

And is it also possible to do the same with posts?

/news/2012/09/17/post-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes update permalink to something like this

[image]